# Failing to run/build fresh dapptools project after importing Uniswap v3

Tags: testing, dapptools

Am i missing something simple here =[ ? I tried to mimic what was done [here](https://github.com/dapp-org/radicle-contracts-tests/) as per the docs.

**Exception**

```
fatal: cannot change to 'lib/v3-core/src': No such file or directory
child_process.js:661
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: git -C lib/v3-core/src rev-parse HEAD
fatal: cannot change to 'lib/v3-core/src': No such file or directory

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:640:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:658:15)
    at run (/nix/store/3ndc11drccg1l1hwmzm3crhi9wsxzbvr-dapp-0.35.0/libexec/dapp/dapp-remappings:77:35)
    at /nix/store/3ndc11drccg1l1hwmzm3crhi9wsxzbvr-dapp-0.35.0/libexec/dapp/dapp-remappings:40:16
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at findRemappings (/nix/store/3ndc11drccg1l1hwmzm3crhi9wsxzbvr-dapp-0.35.0/libexec/dapp/dapp-remappings:17:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/nix/store/3ndc11drccg1l1hwmzm3crhi9wsxzbvr-dapp-0.35.0/libexec/dapp/dapp-remappings:5:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32) {
  status: 128,
  signal: null,
  output: [
    null,
    '',
    "fatal: cannot change to 'lib/v3-core/src': No such file or directory\n"
  ],
  pid: 80819,
  stdout: '',
  stderr: "fatal: cannot change to 'lib/v3-core/src': No such file or directory\n"
}
 dapp-build: building with linked libraries
ParserError: Source "ds-test/test.sol" not found: File not found.
 --> src/DappError.t.sol:4:1:
  |
4 | import "ds-test/test.sol";
```

**Repro**

```
dapp init
dapp install Uniswap/v3-core
dapp test
```

FWIW above result is the same if using `dapp install https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core`

**remappings.txt**
This failure occurs with and without remapping:

```
@uniswap/v3-core=lib/v3-core/
ds-test/=lib/ds-test/src/
ds-test=lib/ds-test/src/index.sol
```

**env**
`export DAPP_REMAPPINGS=$(cat remappings.txt)`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.